# PHP transfer file from other server to user without download it

Tags: php, file, pdf, http-headers

I have other company's API to get file from server like https://xxx-get-super-pdf.com/get/12345

When I open it directly from web-browser it starts to download it. Instead of it I need to show (open) it to user in web-browser in new tab.

I have come up with idea to transfer it via my server to user with other header.

But as I understand when I use something like:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
readfile("https://xxx-get-super-pdf.com/get/12345");
```

It first of all downloads it to my server and then transfers to user. It mean it doubles time to get file, even I don't need to save it and store on server.

Is there any way only ***transfer*** file to user's browser instead of ***download+transfer***

Comment: `Content-disposition:inline` header?

Comment: @nice_dev and? I cant change API. And I don't have the problem with clients side auto-download in browser. My question is how transfer file from api->server->client without downloading it with server (into server cache) in this chain.

Comment: Then hit the API from client browser itself if you wish to eliminate server in between.

Comment: @nice_dev how can I open API link in new tab without downloading PDF file to PC (because that API have `Content-disposition: attachhment` on own side)? I need open PDF in web-browser, not downloading to client device.

Comment: But you previously said  _And I don't have the problem with clients side auto-download in browser_